# Test tool for streaming RTP to specific ports

Tags: testing, rtp, packet-capture

Does anyone know of any tests apps out there (or even libraries that can be used to build one) that let you simply send some G.711 RTP packets out to a specific port? I don't care about the audio content, I literally need some test RTP to make sure my app deals with it correctly when it receives it.

It seems like a really basic thing to want to do but haven't found any tools out there seemingly that will do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use RTP Toolbox.
also this may be helpful: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Open+Source+VOIP+Software

Answer (score 0):

The only product I think is Codima's VoIP Readiness tool as it uses real RTP packets

here is the URL

http://www.codimatech.com/products_X_VoIP_Readiness_Toolbox.php